# Flink CLI gets stuck on running job

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am running a Flink streaming job using the CLI. The client is co-located with Flink's job manager.

The CLI gets stuck on launching the job and fails for timeout expiry:

```
Submitting job with JobID: ca3b6a2931605146a7449d9ff33f4c04. Waiting for job completion.
Connected to JobManager at Actor[akka.tcp://flink@jobmanager:6123/user/jobmanager#927320081] with leader session id 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000.

------------------------------------------------------------
 The program finished with the following exception:

org.apache.flink.client.program.ProgramInvocationException: The program execution failed: Couldn't retrieve the JobExecutionResult from the JobManager.

    [...] // ask if you want the complete trace

Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActorSubmissionTimeoutException: Job submission to the JobManager timed out.
You may increase 'akka.client.timeout' in case the JobManager needs more time to configure and confirm the job submission.
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobSubmissionClientActor.handleCustomMessage(JobSubmissionClientActor.java:119)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActor.handleMessage(JobClientActor.java:251)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.FlinkUntypedActor.handleLeaderSessionID(FlinkUntypedActor.java:89)
    at org.apache.flink.runtime.akka.FlinkUntypedActor.onReceive(FlinkUntypedActor.java:68)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor$$anonfun$receive$1.applyOrElse(UntypedActor.scala:167)
    at akka.actor.Actor$class.aroundReceive(Actor.scala:467)
    at akka.actor.UntypedActor.aroundReceive(UntypedActor.scala:97)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.receiveMessage(ActorCell.scala:516)
    at akka.actor.ActorCell.invoke(ActorCell.scala:487)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.processMailbox(Mailbox.scala:238)
    at akka.dispatch.Mailbox.run(Mailbox.scala:220)
    at akka.dispatch.ForkJoinExecutorConfigurator$AkkaForkJoinTask.exec(AbstractDispatcher.scala:397)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinTask.doExec(ForkJoinTask.java:260)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool$WorkQueue.runTask(ForkJoinPool.java:1339)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinPool.runWorker(ForkJoinPool.java:1979)
    at scala.concurrent.forkjoin.ForkJoinWorkerThread.run(ForkJoinWorkerThread.java:107)
```

What I found interesting is that, if I manually submit the job by using the web UI, everything goes well!

The job has a big pipeline and a big number of tasks, I don't have the same problem with smaller pipelines. However I don't get why there is a discrepancy between web UI and CLI...

Can you tell me what I am missing?

If the only solution is to use the web UI, is there anyway I can do to submit jobs programmatically in this way?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Have to tried to increase `akka.client.timeout` as suggested by the error message?

Comment: Yep yep. I set `akka.client.timeout` and `akka.ask.timeout` to 10 minutes.

Comment: OK, just wanted to make sure. I assume that didn't help.

Comment: A yes, sorry I forgot, the exception above is obtained with the timeout of 10 minutes set

Comment: I am now submitting jobs using the REST API without any problem

Comment: @affo How did you resolve this issue? Could you consider answering your own question if you've managed to solve it?

Thank you!

Comment: I solved by submitting programmatically via REST APIs. Don't know if this was solved with newer versions of Flink